# What is the antd equivalent of Bootstrap 4 spacing utilities?

Tags: antd

In Bootstrap 4, you can use these utilities:

> Bootstrap includes a wide range of shorthand responsive margin and padding utility classes to modify an element’s appearance.
>
> The classes are named using the format {property}{sides}-{size} for xs and {property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size} for sm, md, lg, and xl.
>
> Where property is one of:
>
> ```
> m - for classes that set margin
> p - for classes that set padding
> ```
>
> Where sides is one of:
>
> ```
> t - for classes that set margin-top or padding-top
> b - for classes that set margin-bottom or padding-bottom
> l - for classes that set margin-left or padding-left
> r - for classes that set margin-right or padding-right
> x - for classes that set both *-left and *-right
> y - for classes that set both *-top and *-bottom
> blank - for classes that set a margin or padding on all 4 sides of the element
> ```
>
> Where size is one of:
>
> ```
> 0 - for classes that eliminate the margin or padding by setting it to 0
> 1 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .25
> 2 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .5
> 3 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer
> 4 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 1.5
> 5 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 3
> auto - for classes that set the margin to auto
> ```

In essence I can set a margin right to an element, for instance, using `mr-3` or `mr-2`, depending on how much margin I want.

What is the equivalent of these spacing utilities in Ant Design?

Comment: Doesn't look to me like there are any ☹️

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative: https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-css-utilities

```
import 'antd-css-utilities/utility.min.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

`Antd` doesn't have any type of these functionalities yet. You will have to define your own classes manually in CSS and use them with your components.

Comment: And likely never will: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/8624#issuecomment-351925851